# Interpretation of invariant mass distribution plots

Tags: particle-physics, data-analysis

Can someone explain what exactly a invariant mass distribuition is and how to interpret the follwing graph. Especially what Events/GeV means.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is a histogram. Histograms show distributions of some variable, hence the y-axis is a sort of "frequency" or "density". In this case the bins are 10 GeV wide. Hence the y-axis is number of events per 10 GeV interval.

The black points are data, presumably with poisson error bars. The solid part I assume is a stacked histogram with two components taken from simulation and scaled to have the same total number of events as the data sample.

On the bottom is the ratio of the number of observed and expected background events in each bin. It is consistent with being flat at 1, so there's no signal here.